# Returning the shortest word

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I want to return the shortest word in this ***Array***
I tried it with the ***reduce method***
but the code doesn't return the right word, this is my code below, any help would be so appreciated.

```js
const shortestWord = arr => arr
  .reduce((a,_,i,ar) => (ar = ar.filter(i => !Number(i)), a = ar[0], ar[i] < a ? a = ar[i] : '', a), '');

let output = shortestWord([4, 'onee', 'two', 2, 'three', 9, 'four', 'longWord']);
console.log(output); // --> 'two'
```

Comment: In this case what should be answer then if `one` is not answer?

Comment: There's nothing in your code that checks the length of anything. You need to use `a.length`

Comment: 'two'  is the right answer

Comment: it gives me an error when i used .length method

Comment: What is `!Number(i)` for? `Number()` doesn't return whether something is a number, it converts it to a number (if it can).

Comment: Why are you using `filter()`?

Comment: it should just return strings

Comment: to filter out the numbers

Comment: You should filter out numbers *before* calling `reduce`, not inside the callback function.

Comment: `!Number(i)` will also filter out a string that looks numeric, except for `"0"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code by first filtering on whether the value is a number, and then you only need to compare string lengths:

```js
const shortestWord = arr => arr
  .filter(i => i != +i)
  .reduce((a,v) => a.length > v.length ? v : a);

let output = shortestWord([4, 'onee', 'two', 2, 'three', 9, 'four', 'longWord']);
console.log(output); // --> 'two'
```

Answer (score 2):

Filter out numbers *before* calling `reduce()`, not inside it. Use `typeof` to test the type, `Number()` is for converting from one type to another.

And in the reduce callback function, you need to compare lengths.

```js
const shortestWord = arr => arr
  .filter(el => typeof el == 'string')
  .reduce((a, el) => el.length < a.length ? el : a);

let output = shortestWord([4, 'onee', 'two', 2, 'three', 9, 'four', 'longWord']);
console.log(output); // --> 'two'
```

Answer (score 2):

We can filter out the numbers using `isNaN` and then using `reduce` compare each word with all the other words. If the current word is smaller than the smallest word we know of, we replace it with the current word:

```js
const shortestWord =
  arr => arr.filter(i => isNaN(i))
  .reduce((a, w, i, ar) => (a = a || ar[0], a = w.length < a.length ? w : a), '');

let output = shortestWord([4, 'onee', 'two', 2, 'three', 9, 'four', 'longWord']);
console.log(output); // --> 'two'
```